# Re-link / trigger a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the a custom datepicker directive and it is inside a ng-repeat. When I modify the values that are passed into the directive from the parent controller, they are not reflecting on the screen and I still see the old values, I checked inside the directives scope and the new values are coming in there but not reflecting on the datepicker.

I tried using rootscope to broadcast that a change has been made and I tried to recompile my directive as follows:

in controller:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('relinkDatepicker');
```

in link function:

```
$rootScope.$on('relinkDatepicker',function(){
                        scope.relink();
                });
scope.relink = function(){
                    console.log(scope);
                    console.log(element[0].outerHTML);
                    $compile(element[0].outerHTML)(scope);
                }
```

This did nothing, even though at the time of recompiling I can see that I have new value in scope.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach, even if it did work, would be more of a hack than a solution. You don't need to recompile directives to get the value to update.

You need to address the problem at hand, which is the value of the scope not being reflected in the view. Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell, but I'd hazard a guess you are changing the scope value in an event that angular doesn't know about (for example a jQuery/jQlite event).

If, for example, you update the view in a click event like  below, be sure to include the **`$scope.apply`** line:

```
angular.module('example', [])

.directive('exampleDirective', function () {

  return {

    restrict: 'E'

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function () {
        scope.$apply( function () {
          scope.someProperty = "someValue";
        });
      });
    }

  }

});
```

This would not work without wrapping the change within `scope.$apply` because angular doesn't know about the `'click'` event. Google "angular digest loop" for more information on this subject.

Comment: Im sorry I cant share code because of some policies, but I am using a jquery datepicker inside the directive and within the onSelect function I am running scope,$apply() once the model has been updated.

Comment: Ok. If you are running `scope.$apply` and it's still not working then your error must be elsewhere. You haven't provided enough information for anyone to help further without randomly guessing, if you can't share any more code then you'll have to work this one out alone I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @Ed, turns out I had to give a timeout of 100ms for it to get in sync with DOM. I have no idea why it works.

Comment: Did you use `$timeout` or `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late, but I've found the easiest way to re-instantiate a directive is to hide/show it via the ng-if directive.